# How to compile ERB in a CSV fixture with rspec / Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, fixtures

I want to compile some ERB into a CSV inside a fixture for my spec.  Here is the CSV:

(spec/fixtures/files/song_info.csv.erb)

```
song id,        song_title
<%= song.id %>, Fun Title
```

In my test, I first create a song so I can interpolate it's `id` into the fixture, then load the CSV.

```
describe "#update" do
  let(:song) { FactoryGirl.create :song }         # create the instance
  let(:csv) { file_fixture("song_info.csv.erb").read } # load the file

  it "finds a song and adds it's title" do        
    # when I look at csv here, it is just a string with the raw ERB 
  end
end
```

What happens inside the test is unimportant.  The issue is that when I check out the contents of `csv` I see that it is just a string with the raw ERB (uncompiled).

i.e. `"song_id, new_song_title, <%= song.id %>, Song Title"`

How do I force the ERB to compile?  Is `#read` not the right `file_fixture` method?  Is it something else completely?

Note:  I know there are other ways to accomplish this without fixtures, but this is a trivial example. I just want to know how to compile ERB into a fixture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an ERB instance and evaluate it:

```
let(:csv) { ERB.new(file_fixture("song_info.csv.erb").read).result(binding) } # load the file
```

`binding` is a bit magical, it will give you an instance of `Binding` class that encapsulates the execution context at this particular place in the code. More info: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Binding.html

If you need custom binding to do more complex operations, you can create a class and generate a binding from there, eg:

```
require 'csv'
require 'erb'

class CustomBinding
  def initialize(first_name, last_name)
    @id = rand(1000)
    @first_name = first_name
    @last_name = last_name
  end

  def get_binding
    binding()
  end
end

template = <<-EOS
"id","first","last"
<%= CSV.generate_line([@id, @first_name, @last_name]) %>
EOS

puts ERB.new(template).result(CustomBinding.new("Yuki", "Matz").get_binding)
```